# How to view H2 file and content from within the Eclipse interface?

Tags: eclipse, h2, viewer

New to Java and Eclipse (SpringBoot), I have embedded an H2 Db and created a table, but I have to go out to a browser every time I want to work with it.

Is there a data/database viewer/explorer in the Eclipse interface?

or perhaps a plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse has the [Data Tools Platform](http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/). I personally prefer to use a specialized program to work with databases [squirrel](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/) (which is also an option for you) but DTP is also usable.

It's usually installed by default but of course it depends on how you installed eclipse. Check if you have the "*Database Development*" perspective and if not install the DTP plugin. You can see a short tutorial [here](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Getting_Started_with_DTP).